# Error in atmel code?

Tags: c, atmel

This is my code in atmel 6 using c :

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int a[][][] initialize_hueristic(int[]);



int main(void)
{
    int goal[3],grid_size[3];
    int i, j, k;
    int hueristic[grid_size[0]][grid_size[1]][grid_size[2]];

    hueristic = initialize_hueristic(grid_size);
    hueristic[0][1][0] = 10;
    PORTA = hueristic[0][1][0];






}


int a[][][] initialize_hueristic(int grid_size[])
{
    int hueristic[grid_size[0]][grid_size[1]][grid_size[2]];
    int i, j, k;
    for(i = 0; i < grid_size[0] ; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < grid_size[1]; j++)
            {
                    for(k = 0; grid_size[2]; k++)
                    {
                            hueristic[i][j][k] = 0;
                    }
            }
    }

    return hueristic;
}
```

The atmel studio tells me the following errors :

1.`incompatible types when assigning to type 'int[(unsigned int)(grid_size[0])][(unsigned int)(grid_size[1])][(unsigned int)(grid_size[2])]' from type 'int'`

2.`expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'initialize_hueristic'`

3.`expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'initialize_hueristic'`

Could someone please tell me the error in my code ??

Comment: What is `int a[][][]`?

Comment: "Heuristic" has the "e" and the "u" the other way around.

Comment: @AbhishekVJoshi : Please upvote the answers if it helped. You may also accept the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple errors in your code. The first is of course the return type of the function. If you have a multiple-dimension array, only the *outermost* dimension can be unspecified, all other dimensions *must* be specified.

The other error is something that the compiler will not catch, but will cause strange behavior when running the program. And it's that the function returns a "pointer" to a local variable. The memory used for the variable `hueristic` is on the function stack, and will not be available once the function returns.

The solution to both these problems is to allocate memory dynamically in the heap, and return that pointer. You of course have to remember to free the allocated memory once you're done with it.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cheat with dynamic memory. You need to be passing a pointer to your heuristic and using malloc. More like this:

```
void initialize_hueristic(int grid_size[], int ***hueristic)
{
    int i, j, k;
    hueristic = (int*)malloc(grid_size[0])
    for (the inner variable)
        malloc the internal memory
        //etc


for(i = 0; i < grid_size[0] ; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < grid_size[1]; j++)
        {
                for(k = 0; grid_size[2]; k++)
                {
                        hueristic[i][j][k] = 0;
                }
        }
}

return hueristic;
}
```

This will create memory that will exist outside this function. Look up dynamic memory and malloc for more help.

Answer (score 0):

The non-trivial error (number 1) is with the line:

```
hueristic = initialize_hueristic(grid_size);
```

This line encapsulates the misunderstanding that you are having with how arrays are managed in C.

You cannot assign entire arrays, or pass them to or return them from functions. You have to either copy the array element-by-element, or (preferably) pass around pointers to the start of the array.

You do not need to dynamically allocate the array (dynamic allocation in embedded contexts is uncommon); however, you do want to pass `hueristic` (as a pointer) to each function which manipulates it.

```
void initialize_hueristic(int hueristic[][A][B], int grid_size[])
{
    int i, j, k;
    for(i = 0; i < grid_size[0] ; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < grid_size[1]; j++) {
            for(k = 0; grid_size[2]; k++) {
                hueristic[i][j][k] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You will need to define the values `[A]` and `[B]` (or whichever names are appropriate for these dimensions) at compile time; inner array dimensions must be fixed at compile time in order to use `[]` notation (this will also get rid of your other two errors).

You can then call this like:

```
initialize_hueristic(hueristic, grid_size);
```

You may decide that the `grid_size` array makes no sense (given that the dimensions are fixed at compile time) and choose to use some constants for these dimensions.

I would also suggest checking the spelling of heuristic (which I presume is the word you intended to use).